# Can an HTML script tag be included in a Javascript variable in a jsFiddle?

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I was trying to answer a user's question here on SO with a jsFiddle example. The example was to dynamically initialized an `iframe` element via Javascript. The content to be displayed by the `iframe` was a valid html document assigned to a variable. Here's the variable assignment:

```
var aValidDoc = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC
\"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0
Transitional//EN\"
\"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">
<html
xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">
<head><title></title><style
type=\"text/css\">@media
screen{html,body{margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;width:100%}p{margin:15px;}}</style>
</head><body><p>This is the content of
the dynmic document.</p><body></html>';
```

Here's a snippet of what I want to do:

```
</p><script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(\"Hi\")</script><body></html>';
```

In fact, even a comment with `<script>` breaks the interface:

```
// below line breaks jsFiddle
// <script type="text//javascript"></script>
```

Here's the fiddle: [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/taa1953/KavDy/)

Is there a way to write the variable assignment to include the `script` tag so as not to break the jsFiddle interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Literally writing `</script>` anywhere in your inline javascript will break the containing html tag.

An easy work-around is to write `"<\/script>"` instead. Since it's inside a string literal, the backslash is dropped and you get `"</script>"`

http://jsfiddle.net/KavDy/2/

Comment: Thank you. Interestingly enough, the code ran the first time just fine. When I ran it a second time, IE complained about cross site scripting. (SO is not allowing me to accept your answer yet. I'll be back.)

Comment: @Karl LOL that's an interesting IE quirk. Refreshing the page fully works however.

Comment: Note that this 'problem' is not specific to JSFiddle. This behavior is part of the HTML standard.

Answer (score 1):

The `</script>` closes the script you can escape it like `%3c/script>` and use `unescape`  to get it back

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/KavDy/3/

Answer (score 0):

jsFiddle puts the script in a [cdata-section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA):

```
<head>
  ...
  <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

    var aValidDoc = '...<script>...</script>...';

    // also in comments:
    // <script type="text//javascript"></script>

  //]]>
  </script>
</head>
```

Yet, they server their documents with a `content-type` of `text/html`, so the cdata won't be parsed correctly as XHTML and the closing `</script>` tag breaks everything.

Getting the document through a XHTML proxy should work, but that's no option. Therefore, you will need to escape it, eg by inserting a backslash or `'+'` (literal concatenation).

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>` is also used. I don't think they want XHTML at all (who does?)

Comment: Why else would you use CDATA-tags? BTW: The doctype seems to be valid in [XHTML5](http://blog.whatwg.org/xhtml5-in-a-nutshell)

Comment: Why does everyone out there use `<img />` with `text/html`? Ignorance I guess. Would have to ask the jsfiddle creator about it. :P